# JQuery traverse DOM and extract node value

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, traversal

I have the following DOM:

```
<div class="qtip qtip-light qtip-active">
   <div class="qtip-wrapper">
      <div class="qtip-borderTop"></div>
      <div class="qtip-contentWrapper">
         <div class="qtip-title">
            <div class="qtip-button"></div>
            **Text I need to extract**
         </div>
         <div class="qtip-content">
            <div class="tooltip">
                <div class="button-container">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
            var link = null;
            var link = $('.qtip-active > .qtip-title').val();
            $('.qtip-active > #button-container').append('<a href=\"mailto:' + link + '\">' + link + '</a>');
                </script>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="qtip-borderBottom"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the variable `link` is always undefined when I would expect it to return the text the node specified. I've been reading the jquery documentation for a few hours but I must be missing something with my logic (or lack there of).

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Can I Kick it? Yes you can...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var link = $('.qtip-active .qtip-title').text();
```

`qtip-title` isn't actually a child of `qtip-active`.

Just to clarify:

```
$("a > b")
```

means the set of all `b` that are children of `a` elements whereas:

```
$("a b")
```

means the set of all `b` elements that are *descendants* of `a` elements.

And of course `qtip-title` isn't an input element so use `text()` not `val()`.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `val` function returns the value of a form element (`<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>`).

Your `.qtip-title` is a regular HTML element, so you should call jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get the contents of the element.

---

Also, you're using the wrong selector.  `A > B` is the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), and will match all `B` elements that are *directly* inside an `A` element.

You need to write `$('.qtip-active .qtip-title)`, using the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), to match all `.qtip-title` elements that appear anywhere inside `.qtip-active`.

---

As ryanulit points out, you also need to change the second selector to `$('.qtip-active .button-container')`.

Comment: Also,  $('.qtip-active > #button-container').append('<a href=\"mailto:' + link + '\">' + link + '</a>'); needs to be changed to  $('.qtip-active .button-container').append('<a href=\"mailto:' + link + '\">' + link + '</a>'); .  button-container is used as a class, not an id in your code.  And, I would suggest moving the javascript outside of your divs as a separate block than within them.